# Are there actually accommodation options in Cần Thơ, Vietnam for less than USD $10?

Tags: budget, accommodation, vietnam

Here in Cần Thơ in Southern Vietnam all the usual ways I use to find cheap accommodation fail to turn up anything less than USD $10 - and that one, where I am now, is quite a bit cheaper than anything else.

I've used:
• HostelBookers
• HostelWorld
• WikiTravel
• WikiVoyage

But are there other cheaper options around that just aren't listed in any of these places?

The hotel I'm at is really fancy for $10 - private bath, hot water, even air con. But I can manage just fine with a lot less. I'm happy with a shared bathroom, bucket shower, and a fan.

I asked at a about five places in the first town over the Cambodian border and half just told me I couldn't stay. I don't know if because they don't take foreigners or because they were full. The other half were all USD $10. I gave up and continued on to Châu Đốc where I knew there was a place for $6 or $7.

Could it be related to the fact that foreigners must register with the police and tourist accommodation does that for you whereas local accommodation is not set up for it?

Are there actual guesthouses here with lower prices than the hotels?

Comment: AirBNB also shows **none** under ten but it does show eighteen at exactly ten.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a cheaper place either. I haven't stayed there, but from what I know in other cities in Vietnam, hostels are not that popular in Vietnam.

Also, Vietnamese people tend to be not that friendly towards foreigners. This has to do with wars and other factors. So, what you heard that they don't accept foreigners is probably a valid one.

I could find a few places at around $8 with decent amenities though. 
[image: main results]
[image: booking.com results]

You can try getting a local to introduce you to a place. Get to know a local (some restaurant would be great - talk to someone casually). There is a very good chance they'll know some good cheap place, and if they introduce you, the guest house will happily accommodate you.

Many small guest houses do not want to pay for the booking engines or they are simply not aware of them. I have seen this a lot in South Asian and South East Asian countries.

Comment: I have to disagree about the friendliness of the locals towards foreigners. I have heard from several tourists that they were often overcharged but I'm avoiding being a tourist and so far everybody's been lovely. That said I'm still avoiding asking locals for recommendations in case that turns out to be the way to get overcharged. What were you using to find those hotels? I don't have a smartphone but I do have a netbook.

Comment: Sure the people are lovely and welcoming. I have a few friends that I still keep in touch with. 
I used booking.com for the search. Hope you'll find a good and cheap place. Enjoy your stay in Vietnam!

Answer (score 1):

I found several accommodations in Can Tho for under $10 on [traveloka.com](https://www.traveloka.com/en/), an Indonesian travel site.

[image]